# Extract from numpy array with coordinates of points

Tags: python, numpy

I'm currently writing a code, and I have to extract from a numpy array.

For example: `[[1,1] , [0.6,0.6], [0,0]])`,  given the condition for the extracted points `[x,y]` must satisfy `x>=0.5 and y >= 0.5`

I've tried to use numpy extract, with the condition `arr[0]>=0.5 & arr[1]>=0.5` however that does not seem to work

It applied the condition on all the elements, and I just want it to apply to the points inside my array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share the code you used?

Comment: [[x,y] for x,y in a if x>=0.5 and y>=0.5]

Comment: Your condition doesn't work because of the way it is being parsed.  Wrap each side of the expression in parenthesis or you will get a `TypeError`

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple conditions to slice an array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 1] , [0.6, 0.6], [0, 0]])
new = a[(a[:, 0] >= 0.5) & (a[:, 1] >= 0.5)]
```

Results:

```
array([[1. , 1. ],
       [0.6, 0.6]])
```

The first condition filters on column 0 and the second condition filters on column 1. Only rows where both conditions are met will be in the results.

Comment: I have one more question: if for example my bounds  are stored in a numpy array (for example i want to extract elements which are pairwise greater than 0.5, then do the same thing with 1, then with 1.5 i.e i store [0.5,1, 1.5] in an array), how would i do it in a nice vectorized way instead of looping over the list?

Comment: @cyborg42 - I'm sure it can be done, but we'd need to know exactly what output format you're looking for. I would recommend asking it as a new question with clear example input and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using python generators.

```
import numpy as np

p = [[1,1] , [0.6,0.6], [0,0]]
result = np.array([x for x in p if x[0]>0.5 and x[1]>0.5 ])
```

You can read more about generators from [**here**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

Also you can try this:-

```
p = np.array(p)
result= p[np.all(p>0.5, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way: firstly look for rows full-filling condition:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1] , [0.6,0.6], [0,0]])
rows = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x:x[0]>=0.5 and x[1]>=0.5,1,a)
```

then use it for indexing:

```
out = a[rows]
print(out)
```

output:

```
[[1.  1. ]
 [0.6 0.6]]
```